# 10000 tether in my account from unknown source what should I do?

Tags: tether

Not sure what I should do? 10000 liquid tether added to my account what should I do and how can they scam me from this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is "liquid tether". But if it's not the regular Tether token, then it's most likely a scam.

There are probably many ways these scams work, but I'd assume the most straightforward way is that when you try to transfer these tokens you are instead asked to sign some other transaction that drains your wallet.